# Telegram bot API error 400 Photo has unsupported extension

Tags: php, api, telegram-bot

I am trying to send a dynamically created png image (php script that generates a png file, [code below]) through one of my telegram bots using "sendPhoto" method.

It works fine when I link a physical png file (in the multipart field parameter), but when I try and use the php file, I receive the following error from Telegram:

> Photo has unsupported extension. Use one of .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png, .tif or .bmp

The PHP code is simple enough, works well when I open the file in my browser (i'm shown a dialog to download the png file and it opens fine on my computer):

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="moo.png"');
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 50);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127); 
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparent); 
ob_start ();
imagepng($image);
ob_end_flush();
imagedestroy($image);
```

Is there a way I can bypass this extension check and send my dynamic image script (file with .php extension) in my telegram request?

Comment: you could make your server to "interpret" .png files as php. (might be the wrong terms now, but I guess you know what I meen)

Comment: thanks. yep, i can use rewrite rules with the web server.. was hoping there was a more elegant solution but beggars cant be choosers :)

Comment: okay, managed to solve the problem and it works great. my mistake had nothing to do with the bot API. What i did wrong was sending the php file when i actually wanted to send the output of the script inside the php file. long story short, flushing the output of the code into a tmpfile and sending it instead of the php file did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

turns out bot API had nothing to do with it.
i wrongfully attached the script file when I really should have needed to attach the script output (duh!) :/
So, flushing the output buffer into a tmpfile and then sending it did the trick

```
    function pngCraft($width = 100, $height = 100, $asBase64 = FALSE)
    {
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagesavealpha($image, true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparent);
        ob_start ();
        imagepng($image);
        $image_data = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean ();
        $out = ($asBase64) ? base64_encode($image_data) : $image_data;
        imagedestroy($image);
        return $out;
    }

    $file = tmpfile();
    fwrite($file, pngCraft());
    fseek($file,0);
    $a = stream_get_meta_data($file);
    $uri = $a['uri'];
    rename($uri, $uri.='.png'); 
    $fields[TG_METHOD_SENDPHOTO_PHOTO] = '@'.$uri;
    $fields[TG_METHOD_SENDPHOTO_CAPTION] = 'Yay!';
```